# Return additional parameters with the partial view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an jQuery ajax function

```
function xyz(){
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "/Hr/DoSomething",
        type: "POST",
        data: { guidPersonId: personId },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
        $('#div').html(data);

if(additional parameter = "x")
{
            displayPopUpNotification();
}
    },
    error: function (error) {
        $('#divTimeOffRequestForSpecifiedPersonEntryForm').hide();
        $('#divTimeOffRequestForSpecifiedPersonEntryFailure').show();
    }
});
}

    [HttpPost]
            public PartialViewResult DoSomething(Guid guidPersonId)
            {
.............
............. Do something
return PartialView("~/Views/Hr/_partial.cshtml", listTimeOffRequests);
    }
```

From the action method I want to return an additional parameter.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have the partial view you are returning contain a hidden field or fields with the additional parameters.  Then check it's value as you are.

Comment: is there any other solution to this?